# How to concat a string and float64 in Go?

Tags: go

I am trying to solve this: http://tour.golang.org/#58

Here is what I have done:

```
#imports omitted
type ErrNegativeSqrt float64

func (e ErrNegativeSqrt) Error() string {
    return "Cannot Sqrt negative number: " + string(e)
}

func Sqrt(f float64) (float64, error) {
    if f < 0 {
        return 0, ErrNegativeSqrt(1)
    }
    # calculate z here...
    return z, nil
}
# main omitted
```

I have also tried `e.String()` and `e.string()` but those didn't work too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try using the `fmt` package

```
import "fmt"
...
return fmt.Sprint("Cannot Sqrt negative number ", float64(e))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I had to use it with float64(e) as hints suggested, otherwise it made an infinite loop. I am not sure why though.

Comment: Ah, yes. Forgot about that. fmt.Print (and other fmt functions) will print the error message of the type if it implement the error interface (has a method Error() string). This will cause fmt.Sprint to call your Error() func, which will call fmt.Sprint, etc,  in a loop